# Who thought up the name Yana?

Tags: doctor-who

Is there any in-universe explanation of where the name Yana came from?

Did the old professor take this name because of what the Face Of Boe had said to the Doctor

> “You are not alone”, the acronym of which is “Yana”

? Or did the Face Of Boe say this because the professor would take on this name,

> billions and billions of

years later?

Or, was it all a pure coincidence and did the Doctor just happen to be reminded of what Boe had said, triggered by professor Yana's name?

Comment: Yana is said to be derived from a Slavic word for river.

Comment: River? But this was a whole year before the Doctor first... ehm... gee, don't those timey-wimey things get you every time.

Comment: Don't forget the Face of Bo is Captain Jack. So he had already met the Master long ago.

Comment: Naah, I don't believe that.

Comment: Possibly a reference to this book:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Yana,_the_Touch_of_Undying

Answer (score 2):

IF we consider that Jack Harkness indeed is The Face of Boe, then we have a simple answer to this, The face of boe would already know the name from his past. 
Without considering that, there's no direct explanation as to how The Master chose the name "yana" in his human form.

Answer (score -3):

Yana was brought up in a previous episode of the same season when the face of boe was keeping things running when the Senate was dead for quite some time. His last words to the doctor were You Are Not Alone. Hence the acronym being yana. The face of boe was telling the Doctor that he wasn't the last of the timelords

Comment: Clearly, the OP knew that the Face of Boe said that. The question is asking if there is a connection between this, and the old professor being named Yana later in the season, in-universe? Out-of-universe, it's probably supposed to tip us off to the fact that the professor was a Time Lord; in-universe, a connection is possible, but not clear.